# Is the term "mizudori" a color?

Tags: animals, colors

Is the term "mizudori" used to describe the color of water (light blue) or is it simply referred to as "water bird" or "waterfowl"? I've been doing some research regarding this term. However, I mostly just came across "waterfowl". However, some other media say it's basically a water color reflected from the sky. Another site has a eye candy pigment called "mizudori green" referred to as "bright blue-green" Is this true?

Comment: Although mizudori alone can't really mean a color, but appending an object before a color name should be common (I'm not sure Peacock Green is a Japanese English or not). Certainly most people won't clearly understand exactly what color mizudori green is, but the phrase per se does not sound odd.

Answer (score 3):

The colour you're thinking about is [水色]{みずいろ} (light blue). This is a different word altogether to [水鳥]{みずとり} (waterfowl).

There is no sense in [this J-J dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%BF%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8A/) that suggests that みずとり can refer to a colour.

> 水上または水辺で生活する鳥の総称。水禽 (すいきん) 。
>
> A general term for birds which live on the water or at the water's edge.

Comment: Oh okay, I guess that's a bit more accurate. It's just some sites like the one related to eye candy pigments had a color called "mizudori green" and Wikipedia saying Italian sky blue, meaning celeste, is the equivalent of sorairo or mizudori. Thank you for clearing up my confusion.

Comment: The person who added that line to Wikipedia clearly just made a typo that never got fixed. The website they linked to as a source for it correctly says mizuiro. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sky_blue&diff=prev&oldid=801088463